# What would be a good way to remove item numbers from a list with bash?

Tags: bash

I have a list of stuff like so

```
1. apple
2. orange
3. banana
```

and I want to remove the numbering so I have

```
apple
orange
banana
```

What would be a good way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
awk '{ print $2; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

A bash solution:

```
$ while read f1 f2
> do
>  echo $f2
> done < file
apple
orange
banana
```

Answer (score 1):

or maybe:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the changes to original file

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]*\. //g' inputfile.txt
```

This will create a new file `output.txt`

```
cat inputfile.txt | sed 's/[0-9]*\. //g' > outputfile.txt
```